# break ajax generated table on click with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

My table generated with ajax. After click on one of its row I want to break this table and insert some content(another table in future) in this gap. But it do not breaks with my ajax.

[here is problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BcsJ.png)

But with same html and without ajax it works ok.

[how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYPzV.png)

My html code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>D. Bef.</th>
            <th>D. Aft.</th>
            <th>Note</th>
            <th>Addr.</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="client-orders">
        <?php foreach ($orders as $order) : ?>
            <tr id="order-row-<?=$order['order_id']?>">
                <td>
                    <input  id="data-<?=$order['order_id']?>">
                </td>
                <td contenteditable="true"><?=$order['debt_payment']?></td>
                <td contenteditable="true"><?=$order['debt_current']?></td>
                <td contenteditable="true"><?=$order['order_note']?></td>
                <td contenteditable="true"><?=$order['address_id']?></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger"></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-info btn-show-details"
                            id="details-btn-<?=$order['order_id']?>"
                            order-id="<?=$order['order_id']?>">details
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>


            <!--BREAK PUT HERE-->


    <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and javascript:

```
    // this ajax shows previous html content (just for case)
    $.ajax({
    url: 'Views/ajax_php/orders.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: {clientId: clientId},
    success: function (data) {
        $('#orders').after(data);
    }
});

var orderId;
$(document).one('ajaxStop', function () {
    $('.btn-show-details').on('click', function () {
        orderId = $(this).attr('order-id');
        // here I insert closing tag, put <p> and open table again
        $('\
        </tbody>\n\
    </table>\n\
</div>\n\
<p> text row row row row row row row row row row row row </p>\n\
<div class="table-responsive">\n\
    <table class="table table-hover">\n\
        <thead>\n\
            <tr>\n\
                <th>Date</th>\n\
                <th>D. Bef.</th>\n\
                <th>D. Aft.</th>\n\
                <th>Note</th>\n\
                <th>Addr.</th>\n\
                <th></th>\n\
            </tr>\n\
        </thead>').insertAfter($('#order-row-' + orderId));
```

Comment: your are breaking table from `</tbody>`. You should first break that `td` and then `tr`.

Comment: do you have any error in the console ?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this will work:

```
     $.ajax({
    url: 'Views/ajax_php/orders.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: {clientId: clientId},
    success: function (data) {
        $('#orders').after(data);
    }
});

var orderId;
$(document).one('ajaxStop', function () {
    $('.btn-show-details').on('click', function () {
        orderId = $(this).attr('order-id');
        // here I insert closing tag, put <p> and open table again
        $('\
       <p> text row row row row row row row row row row row row </p>\n\
      <thead>\n\
            <tr>\n\
                <th>Date</th>\n\
                <th>D. Bef.</th>\n\
                <th>D. Aft.</th>\n\
                <th>Note</th>\n\
                <th>Addr.</th>\n\
                <th></th>\n\
            </tr>\n\
        </thead>').insertAfter($('#order-row-' + orderId));
```

You should first break that column and row and then whole table.

Comment: I've checked. don't work. I inserted that code after </tr> so I don't have to close it... do I? And if I past this code on place where ajax appears - it works. There is some thing with DOM I think.

Comment: exactly same as on first picture

Comment: where is your id `#orders`?

Comment: I got your problem. your are inserting this new table after `#order-row-Id`. Let me update my answer and then you can try

Comment: that id is in main View file. This html content fits there. I did not past that file there. And js file shuld work after this tag <tr id="order-row-<some_id>"></tr>

Comment: I think you need to add only `<thead>` not whole table